# Redefining free memory function in C

Tags: c, free, redefine

I'm redefining memory functions in C and I wonder if this idea could work as implementation for the free() function:

```
    typedef struct _mem_dictionary
    {
        void *addr;
        size_t size;
    } mem_dictionary;

    mem_dictionary *dictionary = NULL; //array of memory dictionaries
    int dictionary_ct = 0;         //dictionary struct counter

void *malloc(size_t size)
   {
    void *return_ptr = (void *) sbrk(size); 

    if (dictionary == NULL) 
        dictionary = (void *) sbrk(1024 * sizeof(mem_dictionary));  




    dictionary[dictionary_ct].addr = return_ptr; 
    dictionary[dictionary_ct].size = size;      
    dictionary_ct++;                 
    printf("malloc(): %p assigned memory\n",return_ptr); 
    return return_ptr;               

    }

    void free(void *ptr)
    {


    size_t i;
    int flag = 0;

     for(i = 0; i < dictionary_ct ; i++){

        if(dictionary[i].addr == ptr){
            dictionary[i].addr=NULL;
            dictionary[i].size = 0;
            flag = 1;
            break;
            }
        }

        if(!flag){
            printf("Remember to free!\n");
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What implementations of `free` are possible depends entirely on your implementation of `malloc`. Strictly speaking, redefinition of either produces undefined behavior, but redefinition of some of the `malloc`-family functions without defining all of them is much worse and sure to crash. I think you need to clarify what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: The implementation of `free` is intimately related to the implementation of `malloc`. Where's `malloc`? As it stands you're not returning anything to the free store with your `free`, so you're causing all clients to leak tons of memory.

Comment: Redefining functions like `malloc` and `free` is a tedious job. I've done tons of adventurous things before, but I don't think I've ever gone this far.

Comment: True, sorry I forgot to add the malloc function already implemented. Edited.

Comment: Oh, man! You are so wrong about `sbrk()` ...

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not. The address you are "freeing" is effectively lost after such a call. How would you ever know that the particular chunk of memory is again available for allocation?

There has been a lot of research in this area, here is some overview - [Fast Memory Allocation](http://www.drdobbs.com/184410558;jsessionid=WVSPMGZ5E4WIFQE1GHRSKH4ATMY32JVN) in Dr. Dobbs.

#### Edit 0:

You are wrong about [`sbrk(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html) - it's not a "better malloc" and you cannot use it as such. That system call modifies *end of process data segment*.

Comment: Good point, I must validate availability, and thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Where do you allocate the memory for the `dictionary`?
2. How do you allocate the memory that `dictionary->addr` is pointing at? Without having the code for your `malloc` it is not visible if your `free` would work.
3. Unless in your `malloc` function you're going through each and every memory address available to the process to check if it is not used by your `dictionary`, merely the assignment `dictionary[i].addr=NULL` would not "free" the memory, and definitely not keep it for reuse.

BTW, the `printf` function in your version of `free` would print `Remember to free!` when the user calls free on a pointer that is supposedly not allocated, right? Then why "remember to free"?

**Edit:**

So with that `malloc` function, no, your `free` does not free the memory.  First of all, you're losing the address of the memory, so every time you call this `malloc` you're actually pushing the process break a little further, and never reuse freed memory locations.  One way to solve this is to somehow keep track of locations that you have "freed" so that next time that `malloc` is called, you can check if you have enough available memory already allocated to the process, and then reuse those locations.  Also, remember that `sbrk` is a wrapper around `brk` which is an expensive system call, you should optimize your `malloc` so that a big chunk of memory is requested from OS using `sbrk` and then just keep track of which part you're using, and which part is available.

Comment: I believe that using the flag variable is unnecessary

Comment: Yeah, I edited the question and added the malloc function, and the comment "remember to free" is just a quote in my draft for myself testing the compiled program hehe.